# TikZ item cutting into table

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the image below, the text from Ti*k*Z overlaps with the table caption. How do I fix this?

[image]

I am not able to reproduce it on another `Overleaf` project without including every single item so this is the best I have. Any tips? Is there a command like `\nooverlap`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t!]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the best intercol. separation
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{15}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distractor (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Contact (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Overall (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Accuracy (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Human (cm)}   \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13} \cmidrule{14-16} 
Method & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* \\
\midrule
MTGCN & 23.2 & 35.7 & 35.1 & 41.8 & 62.9 & 61.1 & 22.5 & 50.1 & 49.3 & - & - & - & 25.8 & 41.22 & 39.2 \\
CAHMP & 19.3 & 33.2 & 32.4 & 38.2 & 59.4 & 58.0 & 19.6 & 45.7 & 44.2 & - & - & - & 21.3 & 36.1 & 35.5 \\
Mod & 18.8 & 32.8 & 31.9 & 36.4 & 56.6 & 54.6 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 42.1 & - & - & - & 20.2 & 35.6 & 34.6 \\
\midrule
Ours      & \textbf{3.39} & \textbf{10.8} & \textbf{10.2} & \textbf{21.0} & \textbf{45.0} & \textbf{42.2} & \textbf{8.7} & \textbf{25.8} & \textbf{24.4} & 84.0 & 86.5 & 88.6 & \textbf{16.4} & \textbf{31.9} & \textbf{29.8} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
w/o clf   & 20.2 & 35.4 & 34.3 & 39.5 & 61.5 & 60.4 & 20.9 & 46.3 & 44.8 & - & - & - & 22.2 & 36.7 & 36.2 \\
w/ GT CT  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 18.3 & 40.4 & 38.1 & 10.3 & 24.1 & 23.1 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 15.8 & 27.1 & 25.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Our method continues to show improvements over the SOTA on the noisier KIT RGBD dataset.}
\label{fig:quantitative_kit_rgbd}
\end{table*}

\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.1em}}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagea) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagea.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageb.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}
    
\draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageb.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{fig:qualitative_kit_mocap}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I tried to "draw that line and place that node in the same tikzpicture you place the other stuff"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t!]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the best intercol. separation
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{15}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distractor (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Contact (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Overall (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Accuracy (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Human (cm)}   \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13} \cmidrule{14-16} 
Method & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* \\
\midrule
MTGCN & 23.2 & 35.7 & 35.1 & 41.8 & 62.9 & 61.1 & 22.5 & 50.1 & 49.3 & - & - & - & 25.8 & 41.22 & 39.2 \\
CAHMP & 19.3 & 33.2 & 32.4 & 38.2 & 59.4 & 58.0 & 19.6 & 45.7 & 44.2 & - & - & - & 21.3 & 36.1 & 35.5 \\
Mod & 18.8 & 32.8 & 31.9 & 36.4 & 56.6 & 54.6 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 42.1 & - & - & - & 20.2 & 35.6 & 34.6 \\
\midrule
Ours      & \textbf{3.39} & \textbf{10.8} & \textbf{10.2} & \textbf{21.0} & \textbf{45.0} & \textbf{42.2} & \textbf{8.7} & \textbf{25.8} & \textbf{24.4} & 84.0 & 86.5 & 88.6 & \textbf{16.4} & \textbf{31.9} & \textbf{29.8} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
w/o clf   & 20.2 & 35.4 & 34.3 & 39.5 & 61.5 & 60.4 & 20.9 & 46.3 & 44.8 & - & - & - & 22.2 & 36.7 & 36.2 \\
w/ GT CT  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 18.3 & 40.4 & 38.1 & 10.3 & 24.1 & 23.1 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 15.8 & 27.1 & 25.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Our method continues to show improvements over the SOTA on the noisier KIT RGBD dataset.}
\label{fig:quantitative_kit_rgbd}
\end{table*}

\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.1em}}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagea) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagea.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageb.north west) {\tiny{1}};
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageb.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}
    
\draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageb.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{fig:qualitative_kit_mocap}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

and it resulted in this. How do i fix this ?

[image]

There is no longer any "overlay" in my code but it still looks wrong. What should I do ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[twocolumn,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t!]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the best intercol. separation
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{15}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distractor (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Contact (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Overall (cm)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Accuracy (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Human (cm)}   \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13} \cmidrule{14-16} 
Method & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* & $-1$:0 & 0:2 & 0:2* \\
\midrule
MTGCN & 23.2 & 35.7 & 35.1 & 41.8 & 62.9 & 61.1 & 22.5 & 50.1 & 49.3 & - & - & - & 25.8 & 41.22 & 39.2 \\
CAHMP & 19.3 & 33.2 & 32.4 & 38.2 & 59.4 & 58.0 & 19.6 & 45.7 & 44.2 & - & - & - & 21.3 & 36.1 & 35.5 \\
Mod & 18.8 & 32.8 & 31.9 & 36.4 & 56.6 & 54.6 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 42.1 & - & - & - & 20.2 & 35.6 & 34.6 \\
\midrule
Ours      & \textbf{3.39} & \textbf{10.8} & \textbf{10.2} & \textbf{21.0} & \textbf{45.0} & \textbf{42.2} & \textbf{8.7} & \textbf{25.8} & \textbf{24.4} & 84.0 & 86.5 & 88.6 & \textbf{16.4} & \textbf{31.9} & \textbf{29.8} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
w/o clf   & 20.2 & 35.4 & 34.3 & 39.5 & 61.5 & 60.4 & 20.9 & 46.3 & 44.8 & - & - & - & 22.2 & 36.7 & 36.2 \\
w/ GT CT  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 18.3 & 40.4 & 38.1 & 10.3 & 24.1 & 23.1 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 15.8 & 27.1 & 25.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Our method continues to show improvements over the SOTA on the noisier KIT RGBD dataset.}
\label{fig:quantitative_kit_rgbd}
\end{table*}

\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.1em}}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagea) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagea.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageb.north west) {\tiny{1}};
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageb.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\label{fig:qualitative_kit_mocap}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `overlay` PGF/TikZ won't consider any bounding box. (That's usually they point because you want to draw on something else if you're using `remember picture`.) Why don't you draw that line and place that node in the same tikzpicture you place the other stuff? Why do you need another tikzpicture just for that?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I tried it and it did not work

Comment: The code you posted in your edit doesn't implement @Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion. You're still using `overlay` and separate pictures. TeX can't account for the size if you use this method. Either you have to ensure there's space manually or, far easier in this case, just put it in the picture normally.

Comment: there is no longer an overlay in my code but it still looks wrong. What do I do ? @cfr

Comment: How is it meant to look? 'Looks wrong' is hard to guess. Do you actually need subfloats here or could you just use a single picture? I don't know what you're trying to do, so it's hard to say ....